# delete xml node using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

admin
      
      .
      .
      .
      .
      
        admin

this my xml file.
when i user clear()or del method it will clear all the child and a blank node is creating

> `<user/>`

How can i avoid creating this blank node

it will make problem when i use findall() and try to access any of its child

can anyone provide me a piece of code to del the node fully???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Removing](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#remove) match user node from parent Node would be suitable for this case.